# Spring boot load resources to classpath

Tags: java, spring-boot, resources

I want to load resources under-

```
--src
----test
------jave

--src
----test
------resources
```

To my classpath, so I tried to implement `WebMvcConfigurer`-

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "cptls.pcr.eq.files.s3")
    protected S3Config s3Config() {
        return new S3Config();
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry
                .addResourceHandler("/src/test/resources/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/resources/","classpath:/src/main/resources")
                .resourceChain(true)
                .addResolver(new PathResourceResolver());

        registry
                .addResourceHandler("/test/resources/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/test/resources/","classpath:/main/resources")
                .resourceChain(true)
                .addResolver(new PathResourceResolver());
        registry
                .addResourceHandler("/test/java/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/test/java/","classpath:/main/resources")
                .resourceChain(true)
                .addResolver(new PathResourceResolver());
    }

}
```

And get the resources via-

```
Resource[] resourcesss = resolver.getResources("classpath*:/com/");
```

But for some reason I don't see the resources in resourcesss.

Comment: You do know that there isn't going to be a `src/` directory in your generated JAR/WAR, right?

Comment: My bad, yes I know.